# jmp using table performance (cycle (latency))

Tags: performance, assembly, x86-64

My question is about the performance (cycle (latency)) of the `jmp` in this source code:

```
...
jmp qword [8 * rax + .TABLE]

.... (about 10K instructions)

.TABLE:
   dq .addr1
   dq .addr2
   dq .addr3
   dq .addr4
   ...
   dq .addr1024
```

here the jump table is far from `jmp` (about 10K instructions are between them (for some reason...))
and rax is the index and `RAX` is our index 
so i want to know the type of this JUMP .... what is it ? is it a far jump ? which one of these jumps is my jump ?

```
JMP rel8
JMP rel16
JMP rel32
JMP r/m16
JMP r/m32
JMP r/m64
JMP ptr16:16
JMP ptr16:32
JMP m16:16
JMP m16:32
JMP m16:64
```

and what is the CYCLE (latency) for this jmp ?

Comment: The table is data, not code, you don't even want it in the same page or cache line as executable code.  (That would waste space in L1i / L1d cache, and iTLB / dTLB).  `jmp` doesn't have latency the way `add` or `mov` do - branch prediction + speculative execution handles control dependencies.  But anyway, it's obviously `JMP r/m64` which you could have seen from looking at the opcode in disassembly.

Comment: so you telling me that i have to put the .TABLE in other segment than 'code' segment (for example 'data' segment) and also this is a near jump (since JMP r/m64 is a near jump) ?

Comment: Yes, it's a near jump because it doesn't modify CS, only RIP.  And yes, you should put the table in `section .rodata` (Linux) or `section .rdata` (Windows) like a compiler would.  You don't *have* to, but there's no reason to have it in `.text`.  It's *not code*, it's an array of pointer data that the CPU accesses as data, through the data cache.

Comment: and about performance ... i want to use this type of jump about 10000 times in the function ... i mean by calling the function, about 10000 of this jmp will be execute ... does it have good performance ? or there is a better option ? in fact, my function is depends on this table....

Comment: It could perform fine if it predicts well, and doesn't cause a lot of data cache misses.  You could use a table of 32-bit or 16-bit offsets (movzx load) and compute a jump address relative to a base to reduce data cache footprint, but that's irrelevant for branch prediction.  Profile it with perf counters.

Comment: Ok thank you very much ... it was very helpful (BTW i found full solution for that "THREAD (Clone)" thing too) ... i will update that post ... but Your guidance was helpful too